# problemas com o web scraping

Tags: http, web-scraping

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para fazer web scraping:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
response = requests.get(url)
bytes_html = response.content
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(bytes_html, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')

top_jobs_heading = parsed_html.select_one('#intro > div > div > article > h2')

if top_jobs_heading is not None:
    article = top_jobs_heading.parent

    if article is not None:
        for p in article.select('p'):
            print(re.sub(r'\s{1,}', ' ', p.text).strip())
```

Estou rodando o servidor HTTP na porta 8080 pelo terminal utilizando o código:

```
venv/Scripts/python -m http.server -d aula190_site/ 8080
```

Mas não funciona, o código não retorna o que eu estou pedindo e no outro terminal aparece o seguinte erro:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2023 11:32:27] code 404, message File not found
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2023 11:32:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Como resolver este problema?